# How to display sub Cateogires in Serializer in django-restfmework

Tags: django

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class MiniItems(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    price= models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
class Catagory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    status= models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```
class CatagoryItems(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    price= models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    catagory = models.ForeignKey(Catagory, related_name='catagoryItems', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    MiniItems = models.ForeignKey(MiniItems, related_name='Mini', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Catagory, CatagoryItems,MiniItems
from rest_framework import serializers

class MiniItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):     
    class Meta: 
        Mini = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False,many=True)
      
        model = MiniItems
        fields ="__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("Mini","id") 
        depth=2
        def create(self, validated_data):
            jobtag_data = validated_data.pop('name')
            job = MiniItems.objects.create(**validated_data)
            MiniItems.objects.create(job=job, **jobtag_data)
            return job


class CatagoryItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):     
    class Meta: 
        items = serializers.ListField(child=MiniItemsSerializer())   
        model = CatagoryItems 
        fields ="__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("id","items")
        depth=2               
     
      
class  CatagorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:             
        catagoryItems =serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
     )
     
        id = serializers.Field()
        model =  Catagory      
        fields =("id","name","desc","status","catagoryItems",)
        read_only_fields = ("catagoryItems",)    
        depth=2
```

this is the JSON I want

{
"id": 2,
"name": "a",
"desc": "w",
"status": true,
"catagoryItems": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "v",
"desc": "2",
"price": 123,
"created_at": "2020-07-15T10:07:39.612629Z",
"catagory":1,
"MiniItems": {
"id": 2,
"name": "a",
"desc": "2",
"price": 123,
"created_at": "2020-07-15T10:06:45.109160Z"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

models.py

from django.db import models

class MiniItems(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
desc = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
price= models.IntegerField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
Mini =  models.ForeignKey(CatagoryItems, related_name='Mini',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: remove Minitems from CatagoryItems

Comment: You mean `related_name`?